# $.ajaxSetup for Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

$.ajaxSetup is used for ajax call in jquery.
This works perfectly fine if we use jquery ajax.

But in MVC we use Ajax.BeginForm() .the callback handlers are OnFailure,OnSuccess,OnBegin.

Is there a way we can use $.ajaxSetup for Ajax.BeginForm().

**Update**

eg I have used Ajax.BeginForm() in 10 places but instead of writing OnFailure handler for all i just want to write a single common OnFailure in common place like jquery $.ajaxSetup.
Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: The question is titled wrong for the question/answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler methods - 
>   .ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()
>   - rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().

So as suggested, use the corresponding [global AJAX event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) such as [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) for example if you want to handle all your AJAX errors globally:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    console.log('oopsy');
});
```

Comment: I tried $(document).ajaxSetup() and it does not work with Ajax.BeginForm() ??

Answer (score 1):

Im reviewing the code and the library of microsoft for make the comunication with ajax is **jquery.unobtusive-ajax.js** and in that file they rewrited the main functionality for make a request, well only some options. But if they are using jquery why they need to modify that?? And of course with that code all the global hadlers are off.

I made a little modification is not cool but works, with more time i will update this with a cleaner solution.

Open file **jquery.unobtusive-ajax.js**.

Go to function asyncRequest and in the $.extend option you will see the four events **beforeSend, complete, success and error** you can raise the global triggers there.

Original code:

```
complete: function () {
            loading.hide(duration);
            getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"), ["xhr", "status"]).apply(this, arguments);
        },
```

Modified code:

```
complete: function () {
            loading.hide(duration);
            getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"), ["xhr", "status"]).apply(this, arguments);
            $(document).trigger('ajaxComplete');
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using ajax options:

Defined:

```
@{
 AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
 {
    LoadingElementDuration = 2,
    LoadingElementId = "someElementIdToShowLoading",
    UpdateTargetId = "ElementIdToLoadTo"
 };
}
```

Used:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", ajaxOpts)){}
```

See here for a full list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions_properties.aspx